spring batch javax.activation.MimeType com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo.getExpectedMimeType()
I creating batch using spring batch, reading multiple files from xml, in local my flow is already success but when I deploy it to openshift some error is coming. maybe someone Is able to help me.
Thanks
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.activation.MimeType com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo.getExpectedMimeType()']
va:566)â€¨  at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:251)
